# How to assign a value to a property from user input javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello I'm new at JS, would like to get help. Thanks in advance.

I can get value from user input and assign it as a variable but I am looking to make it as a value of property of an instance.

This is html

```
<lebel id="car_builtYear" for="year">Year's Name</lebel>
<input type="text" id="year" value="">


 <lebel id="car_model" for="model">Model's Name</lebel>
 <input type="text" id="model" value="">

<lebel id="car_maker" for="maker">Manufacturer's Name</lebel>
<input type="text" id="maker"  value="">
```

This is JS

```
    var Car = function (maker, model, year) {
    this.maker = maker;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}
```

This is working

```
var Toyota = new Car("Toyota","X",1890);
```

This is not working.

```
var Toyota = new Car(document.getElementById("maker").value,
                     document.getElementById("model").value,
                     document.getElementById("maker").value);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it is a value of property of an instance"?

Comment: WHat stops you from doing this? It's perfectly fine, you just have to make sure the inputs are already filled out when executing that code. You may also just set individual properties by setting `Toyota.maker = someNewMaker`. Also, name varialbes (like `Toyota`) always with lowercase letters at the beginning, to be able to distinguish them from prototypes (like `Car`).

Comment: Sorry, but your formulation of the question does not make much sense. Easier would be: here is what I have, and here is what I need

Comment: Are not maker, model, year  properties of Car object. If so then these would be properties of the instance(Toyota) also. I'm new so I might be wrong. I don't know It doesn't work. Thank your for your help.

Comment: Note that onyl VALUES of variables are passed to functions. the `new Car (...)` copies the **current** values of those fields, future changes won'T be reflected automatically - you hav to update them manually. Google for `event handlers`.

Comment: Correct, they would be public properties of instance as well. Everything in your code looks right. You probably need to show more code, preferably all js code.

Comment: @johannes-h Can you debugging it? or tell me the reasons which prevent it from working. you will need bootstrap.css to work with HTML. you will get it from getbootstrap com.

Comment: No, I really don'T have the time to debug other people'S code. Reading into it would take me almost as long as I'd need to rewrite it I guess. It deosn'T make sense to debug other people'S code if you don'T really have to, it'S always faster if whoever wrote it does this himself.

Comment: @johannes-h I appreciate you for helping me. I don't need you to debug it. I only need the reasons why it doesn't working. If I define var Toyota = new Car("ASD","POI",1659); it works perfectly fine. But do not work when define like this var Toyota = new Car(document.getElementById("maker").value, document.getElementById("model").value,document.getElementById("maker").value); How Can I vote someone comment or like it, am novice at stack?? Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is at page load (which is when you're setting the value of `Toyota`) the inputs *have no value*. If you want to get values and then set the Toyota up, you'll need to listen for changes in the DOM or a form submit event.

Here's a version with preset values. Works fine (check the console): http://jsfiddle.net/rX5ae/

Comment: I want to get value from user input and set them for Toyota(). I don't need predefined value.